# Can receive but not send emails

Tags: email

I can receive emails but not send them from my Android phone. I am using Yahoo mail and a Samsung Galaxy Ace.

Comment: Are you using the stock email client or another client? What are the settings that you are using (ex. Imap, POP, servers and ports)?

Comment: Outgoing: SMTP: mail.btinternet.com, Port:587, Security type:None.

Comment: You're using the [Yahoo! Mail](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.yahoo.mobile.client.android.mail) app, correct, and not the stock email app?

Comment: No i am using the pre-installed email app. My email is run by yahoo but my email is XXXX@btinternet.com and the server is mail@btinernet.com

Comment: @Bonzo: It would be a good idea to edit your question to include that information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[What are the BT Yahoo! Mail settings for outgoing and incoming mail servers?](http://bt.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/6876/%7E/what-are-the-bt-yahoo!-mail-settings-for-outgoing-and-incoming-mail-servers?)

**Incoming Mail (POP3) Server:** mail.btinternet.com with Port 110

**Outgoing Mail (SMTP) Server:** mail.btinternet.com with Port 25

**Account Name/Login Name:** Your email address

<sup>(including the "@btinternet.com" or "@btopenworld.com" part)</sup>

**Password:** Your BT Yahoo! password

### step-by-step

[Online step-by-step instructions to help with your email setup.](http://diagnostics.bt.com/login/?workflow=Email)

Comment: Note that SMTP Authentication needs to be enabled.

Answer (score 2):

I have been experiencing the same problem with a Samsung Galaxy S2 and a BT yahoo account, namely can receive but not send email. After many unsuccessful variations on POP3/IMAP and port combinations the following finally seems to have worked:

incoming IMAP server: [imap.mail.yahoo.com]    [SSL port 993]
[User name is your whole bt email address. Use your normal account password.]

outgoing SMTP server: [smtp.mail.yahoo.com]  [SSL port 465]
(Finally - and crucially - select "require sign in" and use your email address (username) and account password as for the incoming.)

This may only be relevant to the Galaxy S2

Answer (score 1):

I recently acquired an Alcatel PIXI UNITE smartphone from TracFone (April 2017). It uses Android 6.0. I use an att.net email address and when I let the regular email app add that email account I could receive email but never send it. My email would always end up either in the Outbox or in Drafts. And I could not send the mail from there either. There is currently some kind of craziness going on with Yahoo ATT mail. But the trouble seems to have been fixed (at least for now) by going into Settings (for the email account) and changing part of the default outgoing SMTP server settings. The default setting was: android.smtp.mail.yahoo.com. What I finally discovered after days of trial and error was simply to delete the "android." from the default and bingo!

Answer (score 0):

Yahoos settings for android:

`Yahoo Incoming Mail Server (IMAP): android.imap.mail.yahoo.com, SSL (port 993)`

`Yahoo Outgoing Mail Server (SMTP): android.smtp.mail.yahoo.com, SSL (port 365) use auth`

Comment: I don't have the ability to set IMAP, I can only use POP3. I also tried setting outgowing mail server and I just get an error...

Answer (score 0):

I had tried all combinations of security settings but crucially it was the 'request sign in' bit that was needed along with selecting port 465 (SS L certificates option).

Answer (score 0):

I had changed my password online with Yahoo and that was the issue. As soon as I entered my new password, my outgoing messages worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes your app preferences inhibit the default email app functions. This seems quite possible if you've disabled apps recently, or have in the past and there's been a recent update. Try resetting your app preferences.

To reset app preferences:

1. Open Settings app.
2. Tap Apps.
3. Tap More settings (three-dot) icon at the upper right.
4. Tap Reset app preferences.

[This Droid Guy post gives more suggestions.](https://thedroidguy.com/2019/06/galaxy-s8-email-does-not-work-stopped-syncing-cant-send-receive-or-delete-email-messages-1082298)